# How can I add the values of one column based on a groupby in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

`year   count
2001    14
2004    16
2001    2
2005    21
2001    22
2004    14
2001    8`

I want to group by the `year` column and add the `count` column for each given year. I would like my result to be

`year   count
2001    46
2004    30
2005    21`

I am struggling a bit finding a way to do this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df['count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['count'])
#df['count'] = df.groupby(['year'])['count'].sum()

total = df.groupby(['year'])['count'].sum()

print(total)
```

Yields:

```
year
2001    46
2004    30
2005    21
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help !!
Lets assume your pandas dataframe name is ***df***. then groupby code run like below:

```
df.groupby('year')[['count']].sum()
```

It will return dataframe you want.

Comment: This is exactly the same code I posted, but 3 hours later.